# How to get cProfile results from a callback function in Python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, callback, gprof, cprofile

I am trying to determine which parts of my python code are running the slowest, so that I have a better understanding on what I need to fix. I recently discovered [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) and [gprof2dot](https://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) which have been extremely helpful. My problem is that I'm not seeing any information about functions that I'm using as callbacks, which I believe might be running very slowly. From what I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script/1922945#1922945) is that cProfile only works by default in the main thread, and I'm guessing that callbacks use a separate thread. That answer showed a way to get things working if you are using the threading library, but I couldn't get it to work for my case.

Here is roughly what my code looks like:

```
import rospy
import cv
import cProfile
from numpy import *
from collections import deque

class Bla():
  def __init__( self ):
    self.image_data = deque()
    self.do_some_stuff()
  def vis_callback( self, data ):
    cv_im = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv( data, "mono8" )
    im = asarray( cv_im )
    self.play_with_data( im )
    self.image_data.append( im )
  def run( self ):
    rospy.init_node( 'bla', anonymous=True )
    sub_vis = rospy.Subscriber('navbot/camera/image',Image,self.vis_callback)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      if len( self.image_data ) > 0:
        im = self.image_data.popleft()
        self.do_some_things( im )

def main():
  bla = Bla()
  bla.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  cProfile.run( 'main()', 'pstats.out' ) # this could go here, or just run python with -m cProfile
  #main()
```

Any ideas on how to get cProfile info on the vis_callback function? Either by modifying the script itself, or even better using `python -m cProfile` or some other command line method?

I'm guessing it is either the reading of images or appending them to the queue which slow. My gut feeling is that storing them on a queue is a horrible thing to do, but I need to display them with matplotlib, which refuses to work if it isn't in the main thread, so I want to see exactly how bad the damage is with this workaround

Comment: [*This should tell you where to look.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)